# JQuery Dragable - Must stop for div with min height

Tags: jquery

I want this drag-able button not to overlap my cute realizable div r1, it's not just about manners, I want it to stop when `r1` min height reaches.

I want to avoid adding more divs as that will make me resize them too. (it's not complete yet...)

```
<div id="demo">
    <div id="r1">I am resizeable but with min height</div>
    <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
        <p>Drag me</p>
    </div>
    <div id="r2">I am resizeable but with min height</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var $container = $("#demo");

function resizeContainer(e, ui) {
    //resizing 
    var drag = ui.offset.top;

    $("#r1").height(drag);
    $("#r2").height(drag);
}

$("#draggable").draggable({
    axis: "y",
    drag: resizeContainer,
    containment: "#demo"
});
```

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/XLrNF/319/

Comment: i think am after custom containment